# pandas - Create dynamic columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, flatten, normalize

I have a list of dictionary in each row. My goal is to flatten it into a single row

```
0    [{'key': 'ga_session_id', 'value': {'string_va...
1    [{'key': 'source', 'value': {'string_value': '...
2    [{'key': 'firebase_event_origin', 'value': {'s...
3    [{'key': 'firebase_conversion', 'value': {'str...

Name: params, dtype: object
```

Here is a sample of one row:

```
[{'key': 'ga_session_id',
  'value': {'string_value': None,
   'int_value': '1575017974',
   'float_value': None,
   'double_value': None}},
 {'key': 'firebase_conversion',
  'value': {'string_value': None,
   'int_value': '1',
   'float_value': None,
   'double_value': None}},
 {'key': 'firebase_event_origin',
  'value': {'string_value': 'auto',
   'int_value': None,
   'float_value': None,
   'double_value': None}},
 {'key': 'ga_session_number',
  'value': {'string_value': None,
   'int_value': '2',
   'float_value': None,
   'double_value': None}},
 {'key': 'engaged_session_event',
  'value': {'string_value': None,
   'int_value': '1',
   'float_value': None,
   'double_value': None}}]
```

I want iterate each element of a row and create dynamic columns on the fly. For instance:

```
[{'key': 'ga_session_id',
  'value': {'string_value': None,
   'int_value': '1575017974',
   'float_value': None,
   'double_value': None}}, ...]
```

to

```
**ga_session_id.string_value  |  ga_session_id.int_value  | ga_session_id.float_value |  ...**
None                        |  1575017974               | None                      |  ...
```

Same goes to further elements in a row. I am aware we can new populate columns on the fly using apply. This is what I have tried,

```
import itertools as it
df4 = pd.DataFrame.from_records(it.chain.from_iterable(
    i for i in df2['params']))
```

This is the output:
[image]

```
pd.concat([df4.drop('value', axis=1), pd.io.json.json_normalize(df['value']).add_prefix('value.')], axis=1)
```

[image]

However, I have lost track of the row of which the data belongs to. I need some assistance

Comment: Do all elements have the same structure?(`keys`, `depth` etc.)

Comment: yes, they have same structure

Comment: how much records in `list`? why you don't want just create `dict` of `tuples` using iteration?

Comment: Number of records in list are variable, my aim is to flatten all of those records

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a copy of the data frame then iterated row by row creating columns on the fly and adding data in the new (copy) dataframe.

```
tmp_df = deepcopy(df)
col_list = []
for index,row in df.iterrows():
    for element in row[column]:
        cols = ["%s.%s"%(element['key'],key) for key in element['value'].keys()]
        tmp_df = tmp_df.reindex(columns=list(dict.fromkeys(tmp_df.columns.tolist() + cols).keys()))
        tmp_df.loc[index,cols] = element['value'].values()
```